# Find potential logo boundaries on image for further processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition

I try to find potential logo regions in image. To do this, I find the edges of objects and fixing them in the bounding boxes. Then they try to group them into clusters by the similarity of the histogram. But sometimes getting bad results, because the regions are not always has similar region for histogram matching.

I try SIFT/SURF/ORB and Harris Corners for clustering features(key points), and then get bounding box of clusters but its also produces a bad result.

I need something like this (Blue rectangles - bounding boxes of contours finded by OpenCV):

[image: adidas]
[image: zara]

Green rectangles - bounding boxes of clusters (painted by hands in graphics editor)

What the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Your desired goal is unclear. Do you want to find _potential_ logo regions for subsequent analysis and further processing or do you want to identify logos? In the latter case you first need to detect the logo. Usually you get the bounding box for free afterwards.

Comment: I want find only potential logo regions. For identify i use method named pHash.

Comment: I am not familiar with pHash but I think you should try a search-based method based on bag-of-words or a traditional classifier first.

Comment: Ok, Now i use Bag-of-words with Bayes classifier. I'd like to ask if it's possible to determine the exact location of the classified object, like we got the result of "Yes, there's a nike logo", is it possible to get some coordinates, from where we could build up some kind of region to show it's in that region?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions for your problem.

As a start you may have a look into the following paper

> Logo Spotting by a Bag-of-words Approach for Document Categorization
>   Blockquote
>   Marcal Rusinol and Josep Llados [PDF](http://www.cvc.uab.cat/~marcal/pdfs/ICDAR09.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, I read this paper. Approach in paper focused on fax images, but how to spot image in real world logos of stores. Could you explane in short steps, how to find logo spots for different kinds of images?

Comment: Look for object recognition and sliding window search